# What is the best way to reword the following sentence

Tags: editing, rewriting

The sentence is: They reinforce how African-Americans used art, music, and literature to help shape their cultural identity.

This sentence is explaining how the inclusion of details about Harlem Renaissance artists contributes to the development of ideas in the text "The Harlem Renaissance" by Jessica McBirney.

My goal is to make the sentence sound more professional but also completely change the sentence and keep its original meaning.

I tried creating a sentence of my own, but it just doesn't seem quite right.

The sentence I wrote: Their cultural identity was shaped because of how they reinforced how African-Americans used art, music, and literature.

But it just doesn't make sense...

Comment: Hi Honey Boochie Bun, welcome to Writing.SE. I recommend you check out the [help center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help) and what [topics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) can be asked about here. Questions about what to write or how to re-write something are not considered on topic.

Comment: I'm getting the impression you're trying to get this website to edit a homework assignment. Maybe that's not the case, but it does create that impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not this particular sentence, but check if any of the following work for you:

African-Americans have a long and complicated history with the United States. One way that they have expressed their experiences is through their art, music, and literature. These forms of expression have helped shape their cultural identity.

African-Americans have often used art, music, and literature to help shape their cultural identity. In many ways, these forms of expression were used as a form of resistance against the discrimination and racism that African-Americans faced. Through their art, music, and literature, African-Americans were able to communicate their unique experiences and perspectives. These forms of expression also helped to create a sense of community and solidarity among African-Americans.

African-Americans have used art, music, and literature to help shape their cultural identity. In spite of the obstacles they faced, they created a culture that was rich in expression and full of pride. This can be seen in the works of such artists as Aaron Douglas and Romare Bearden, and in the music of Duke Ellington and Miles Davis.

African-American culture is deeply rooted in the history of the United States. African-American art, music, and literature have helped shape the cultural identity of the nation. African-American artists have used their art to express their experiences and to challenge racial injustice. African-American musicians have used their music to express their emotions and to bring people together.

African-Americans have used art, music, and literature to help shape their cultural identity. In particular, the Harlem Renaissance was a time when many African-Americans began to express themselves creatively. The writer Langston Hughes was one of the most important figures of the Harlem Renaissance. He used his poetry to explore the experience of being African-American.